# Solve inequality in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, inequality

I'm trying to solve a simple linear inequality in Sympy but can't seem to get it to work.
Basically, I want to be able to calculate the optimal values of `a` when the inequality happens to be false.

```
import sympy

num_attractors = 4
attractor_size = 64
network_size = 256
a, s, n = sympy.symbols('a s n')
expr = a * (s + 16) <= n

if not expr.subs([(a, num_attractors), (s, attractor_size), (n, network_size)]):
    # compute optimal value for a i.e., the closest integer a s.t. a <= n / (s + 16)
```

I have tried using `solve(expr, a , sympy.Integer)` and `sympy.solvers.inequalities.reduce_inequalities(expr,a)` but can't seem to make sense of their output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`solveset` can be used:

```py
if expr.subs([(a, num_attractors), (s, attractor_size), (n, network_size)]) != True:
    asol = solveset(expr.subs([(s, attractor_size), (n, network_size)]),a,S.Integers)
>>> asol
{..., 2, 3}
>>> _.sup
3
```

You can also just take the `floor` of the solution to the equality (and do so symbolically):

```py
>>> ans = floor(solve(expr.lhs - expr.rhs, a)[0]); ans
floor(n/(s + 16))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!
One thing that's not clear for me is why `asol = Range(-oo, 4, 1)` but `atol.sup = 3`.  Is there a flag somewhere within `asol` that states that the solution is the open interval (-Inf, 4) and not the half-closed (-Inf, 3]?

Comment: `asol` is a `Range` object that has semantics like the Python `range`; the end point is not included.